# Apache Shiro: Howto set principalSuffix in JndiLdapContextFactory?

Tags: java, security, shiro

In Shiro's [DefaultLdapContextFactory](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/DefaultLdapContextFactory.html) it was possible to set a [principalSuffix](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/DefaultLdapContextFactory.html#setPrincipalSuffix(java.lang.String)).

Since DefaultLdapContextFactory deprecated and [JndiLdapContextFactory](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/JndiLdapContextFactory.html) should be used instead, I wonder how to set a principalSuffix there.

I don't want to hard-code it, and found no way to define it in JndiLdapContextFactory.

Comment: i do have the same problem using the `ActiveDirectoryRealm` which uses the deprecated `DefaultLdapContextFactory`. The replacement `JndiLdapContextFactory` however does not yet support the 'searchBase' or 'principalSuffix'. Currently I stick to the `DefaultLdapContextFactory` and hope they'll fix that problem in the meantime.